# Overwriting Console.log to Support Console.re.log to Debug iOS Chrome

Tags: javascript, console

I don't have any Apple devices and I'm trying to debug iOS Chrome. Sadly, browserstack doesn't have console support yet for iOS Chrome. I found this neat websocket console logger tool https://console.re/

It asks you to use special syntax to log to their app. You have to write console.re.log('message'). However, I'm trying to log everything to see where my app is breaking. I tried using the following code but I get problems with it going into infinite loops since console.re.log also calls console.log and I'm adding console.log to console.re.log... Here's the code:

```
<script>
    console.log(window.location.href.slice(-5));
    if(window.location.href.slice(-5) === 'debug') {
          var consolere = {
            channel:'music-blobs',
            api:'//console.re/connector.js',
            ready: function(c) {var d=document,s=d.createElement('script'),l;s.src=this.api;s.id='consolerescript';s.onreadystatechange=s.onload=function(){if(!l){c();}l=true;};d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}};
          var _log = console.log;
          var _error = console.error;
          var _warning = console.warn;
          var logQueue = [];
          var errorQueue = [];
          var warnQueue = [];
          var parseQueueRan = false;
          consolere.ready(function() {
            console.log = console.re.log;
            console.warn = console.re.warn;
            console.error = console.re.error;
          });
          window.console.log = function(...items) {
            if(console.re) {
              console.re.log(message);
            } else {
              logQueue.push(message);
              _log.apply(console, arguments);
            }

          }
          window.console.error = function(message) {
            if(console.re) {
              console.re.error(message);
            } else {
              errorQueue.push(message);
              _warning.apply(console, arguments);
            }

          }
          window.console.warn = function(message) {
            if(console.re) {
              console.re.warn(message);
            } else {
              warnQueue.push(message);
              _error.apply(console, arguments);
            }
          }
        }
  </script>
```

Anybody know how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Its old, but for further Googlers:
My simple solution is:
console = console.re;
...and every log will be shown on console.re/